# Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded on iOS Simulators over 12

Tags: react-native, ios13

I've inherited a react-native mobile app and am slowly making headway learning both react-native and the app itself.

I've run into an issue that I can't make headway on.

I can run the app perfectly fine in Xcode 12 on iOS simulators less than 13. However, on 13.5 or 14 I get the app splash screen and then the immediate error of *Maximum call stack size exceeded*. The screen shows the traced exception coming from loadModuleImplementation in require.js. I've put debug statements in require.js and I can see all the modules being loaded in iOS 12 versus iOS 13.5. There are hundreds of components being loaded, but substantially less are loaded before I get the error in 13.

I believe the app published in the app store works fine on 13 and 14... at least I've been told I have the code that has built the store version.

The app has over a dozen react-native components it uses.

react : 16.8.3

react-native : 0.59.9

react-native-device-info : 5.6.2

and on...

Using node 10, npm 5.6.0, Metro Bundler

It appears the previous developers stopped upgrading react-native at 0.59.9 because of the changes needed to go to 0.60.0. I've tried to upgrade but it appears to be a lot of work.

I'm looking for advice as to where to spend my time next to resolve this. Is this an issue with this version of react-native and iOS 13+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to see what is being loaded in app.js. Comment everything out and gradually add everything back again and you might spot the error.

Comment: Maybe obvious but just the direction a newbie like me needed. I wound up drilling into deep imports which took some effort but I've narrowed down where the issue is. Still working on it, but much progress has been made. Thanks!